# How to get running result for balance sheet in ClickHouse

Tags: database, aggregation, clickhouse

Assume I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| id      | operation  |amount  |
+---------+------------+--------+
| 1       | add        |10      |
| 2       | add        |10      |
| 1       | sub        |5       |
| 1       | sub        |5       |
| 2       | sub        |10      |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

I want to transform it into something like this, where every next `actual records` column contains all array elements from the previous row with added/removed elements from the current row based on the value in `operation` column:

```
+---------+------------+--------+------------------------+
| id      | operation  |amount  | actual records         |
+---------+------------+--------+------------------------+
| 1       | add        |10      | [(1,10)]               |
| 2       | add        |10      | [(1,10),(2,10)]        |
| 1       | sub        |5       | [(1,5),(2,10)]         |
| 1       | sub        |5       | [(2,10)]               |
| 2       | sub        |10      | []                     |
+---------+------------+--------+------------------------+
```

Is it possible at all with ClickHouse only? Might window functions be in help?

Comment: It's possible using arrays and WindowFunctions but the problem that it may require to put all rows into memory, how many elements in a group?

Comment: it is going to be a report on 4-5M rows, which is about 2G I think